# How to include pagination in label page

Tags: pagination, tags, label, blogs, blogger

I am create a blog using blogger.com.When I click on a label (Or tag ) I get back to the homepage, while the relevant label posts should load. Ideally I want to load max posts 20 per page and pagination to see more.
My code is,

```
<b:widget id='HTML44' locked='false' title='Label' type='HTML'>
<b:includable id='main'>
<b:if cond='data:blog.url != data:blog.homepageUrl'>
<b:if cond='data:blog.pageType != &quot;item&quot;'>
<!-- only display title if it's non-empty -->
<b:if cond='data:blog.searchLabel != &quot;&quot;'>
<h2 class='title' id='tit_h2'><img border='0' src='http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-uqDJqtNSkfY/UyElenxHsDI/AAAAAAAAAGk/4QaOO27tY0w/s1600/Heading+1.png' style='margin-top:-2px; float:left; margin-right:10px;'/><data:blog.searchLabel/></h2>
<div class='eggTray'>
<script src='http://helplogger.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/listbadge.js'>{&quot;pipe_id&quot;:&quot;1a6640e2a78b2c6e736f2220529daae5&quot;,&quot;_btype&quot;:&quot;list&quot;,
 &quot;pipe_params&quot;:{&quot;URL&quot;:&quot;http://www.foxbet.gr/feeds/posts/default/-/<data:blog.searchLabel/>&quot;},
&quot;hideHeader&quot;:&quot;false&quot;,&quot;height&quot;:&quot;auto&quot;,&quot;count&quot;: 20  }</script>
<div class='ycdr' style='font-family: arial, sans-serif; font-size: 9px;'><a href='http://helplogger.blogspot.com/2012/05/recent-posts-widget-with-thumbnails-for.html' target='_blank' title='Grab this widget'>Recent Posts Thumbnails</a> <a href='http://helplogger.blogspot.com/' target='_blank'>Blogger Widget</a></div><noscript>Your browser does not support JavaScript!</noscript></div>
<style type='text/css'>
.ybi{display:block;}
.eggTray {margin:10px 0px;padding:0px;}
.ybr li  {border-bottom:0px #cccccc dotted; padding:0px 0px 10px 0px!important;}
.pipesTitle {padding-top:0px;}
.pipesDescription {display:true;}
.ycdr {display:none; background:transparent url(http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-oxTuqVj1ziA/T6P6wtxqsgI/AAAAAAAACBE/wWR0bb2gfuE/s1600/logo.png) 0px 0px no-repeat; padding: 1px 0px 0px 19px; height:14px; margin: 4px 0px 0px 0px;line-height:14px;}
.ycdr, .ycdr a {color:#999999;}
.widget .popular-posts ul {padding-left:0;}
.pipesThumbnail{width: 70px !important; height: 50px !important;}
.pipesThumbnail img{width: 100% !important; height: auto !important;}
</style>
<div class='widget-content'>
<data:content/>
</div>
<b:include name='quickedit'/>
</b:if> </b:if></b:if>
</b:includable>
</b:widget>
```

Any one please help me

Answer (score 1):

Considering you have a pagination script in your template.

Now For pagination scripts to work on your labels aswell, you need to specify parameters in URL.

**Example:**

```
http://yourblog.blogspot.com/search/label/posts?&max-results=20
```

here `posts` will be replaced by your label name.

`&` parameter will enable pagination on your labels aswell.

`max-results=20` will load 20 posts maximum (this can be changed by your choice)

Hope this helps.